# What is the plural of "cost"?

Tags: grammatical-number, irregular-plurals

I'm not sure whether the plural of "cost" is "cost" or "costs". Like "information" is as well singular as plural - I think you can't have "one cost"? So it has to be "cost" in plural?
Something like the following sentence:

> The cost(s) of those products are higher than the revenues.

Comment: As far as I know, the word "information" is never plural in typical English any more than the word "gravel" is. Be careful not to confuse noncount nouns with grammatically plural nouns. It makes some sense to say that a noun is "plural" if it takes plural verb agreement, or can be referred to with a plural pronoun, or has a plural suffix, but none of these are true of "information". We say things like "**This** information **is**...," not "**These** information **are**...", and "They sent me some information about X, and I relayed **it** to Y", not "I relayed **them** to Y".

Comment: _Cost_ is a noun derived from the verb _cost_, and it refers to single commercial transactions. Therefore it has a plural, and the plural is _costs_. This is also the third-person singular present tense of the verb, as in _That costs $3.95_. This is completely regular behavior in English, verbs and nouns, and has nothing to do with "information" or with "being both plural and singular".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [*Merriam-Webster*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cost), the plural is in fact ***costs***. (I know it applies *costs* in a legal sense in definition 3, so look at the example sentences.)

As far as your example sentence goes, if I understand it correctly, you should use *costs* not only to match plural “revenues” but also because each individual item most likely has its own expenses associated with it—it does not contribute to a single expense for multiple items.

Comment: yeah each product could also have multiple costs then..

Comment: @MatthiasBurger “The cost of each product is higher than its revenue” could resolve that problem.

Comment: but e.g. a product has material-cost, personal-cost,... so wouldn't it be "The costs of each product are..."

Comment: @MatthiasBurger Yes, that works as well. It simply depends on the context.

Comment: @MatthiasBurger You could even go with “The various costs of the products.”

Comment: @Matthias Burger 'The cost of each product is higher than the revenue it generates' is far better than 'The costs of each product are higher than the revenue it generates'. 'Cost' by default here means 'total cost associated with'. The mass-noun usage is the one far more commonly encountered in everyday language; 'costs' (and 'costing' as a gerund) are more at home in financial registers.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Excellent technical insight! Thank you for contributing that :) I learned something new from you, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

'What are the costs involved in upgrading our office?', suggests there are several categories of expense, not just one.

Comment: You've been answering a bunch of questions recently- could you please add some details and sources to your (existing/future) posts? Answers on this site are expected to actually _answer_ the question.

Answer (score -1):

Note that on the Merriam-Webster site, they disclaim the accuracy of the "example" sentences at the bottom of each entry, as those are compiled from the web (not a reliable source for grammatical excellence). They even ask for feedback on those auto-generated examples. I would suggest using *only* the actual definition and any examples within that definition, and not the compiled examples at the bottom of the entry, as guidelines.

Comment: Please don't use answers to comment on other responses. Answers should only be used to directly answer the question.

Comment: The compiled examples aren't guaranteed correct, but they offer examples of current usage. They're not completely valueless, but you should evaluate each one yourself, e.g. do they come from a source with a good reputation for editing and quality of writing. I'd trust the Wall Street Journal more than the opinion of a random person on the internet.